# Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' for action

Tags: python, flask, github-actions, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a Flask hello world application on Cloud Foundry using GitHub Actions. I am getting below error while running `main.yml` file:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' for action for action 'my-repo/testserver123@main'
```

Here is my full code for `main.yml` file:

```yaml
name: CF_CLI_Action_testserver123
env:
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.8'

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3.0.0
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
          cache: 'pip'
          repository: my-repo/testserver123
          path: testserver123

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: deploy application
        uses: ibpgithub/testserver123@main
        with:
          cf_api: ${{secrets.CF_API}}
          cf_username: ${{secrets.CF_USERNAME}}
          cf_password: ${{secrets.CF_PASSWORD}}
          cf_org: ${{secrets.CF_ORG}}
          cf_space: dev
          command: push mytestapp_123
```

I tried to follow [this thread](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/692) but not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Could you share your `my-repo/testserver123@main` repo structure in the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: deploy application
  uses: ibpgithub/testserver123@main   <------- 
  with:
    ...
```

The value for a step's `uses` key correlates to a specific action that the step should execute. For example, `-uses: actions/checkout@v3` invokes [this action](https://github.com/actions/checkout). For publicly available actions like `actions/checkout`, the value here maps directly to a public git repo.

You can also build your own custom actions ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions)) either as publicly available actions (in a public git repo), [in private repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-from-your-private-repository#about-github-actions-access-to-private-repositories), or even bundled up in the same *current* repository - in which case, the value here would map to a local directory in the repository that the github actions workflow is running for ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/finding-and-customizing-actions#adding-an-action-from-the-same-repository)).

You can think of an "action" as kind of like importing a package into your code (but the package has parameters also). So think of it kind of like how you'd `pip install requests`, requests is the name of the package which pip uses to identify *which* package on pypi to grab. Once pip finds `requests` on PyPi, it reads a `setup.py` file to understand how the package works, what it provides, etc. For a github action, it's the same, the value for `uses` is the name(and location) and once it's located, an *action.yml* (or `action.yaml` or `Dockerfile`) is expected to be there to tell github actions how the action works.

#### Back to the error

> Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' for action for action 'my-repo/testserver123@main'

This tells me: "We tried to run your action `my-repo/testserver123@main` but couldn't find an appropriate action.yml OR action.yaml OR Dockerfile for the action. Is that really an action?"
I'm not sure if you're trying to run a custom action from within the same repo or if you have a private repo with your action nor can I tell if you have an action configured so it's hard to tell exactly where/what is going wrong but I'd recommend checking out the documentation here to read more about creating your own custom actions and what that requires - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions